# No emulator device found in my visual studio to run my android app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Today i download the `visual studio 2015` .because i want to start android programming.

So i download `xamarin for visual studio` as you can see here :

[image]

So other packets are installed as you can see here :

[image]

So i create a `blank apps` and the code is like this :

```
namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

I install this file but i don't know what is that exactly i think it is simulator `mono-4.2.2.30-gtksharp-2.12.30-win32-0`.

But when i run this program

[image]

I get this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     @(Content) build action is not supported    App1    C:\Users\ehsan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image]

Some thing that i should add is there is no emulator in the list of visual :

[image]

The sdk manager :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things for getting the emulator to work properly -

1. Install the necessary components in the SDK manager for the Android version you are targetting. Along with System Image.
2. For that system image you can choose a preset virtual device present in the AVD Manager.

Then launch the Emulator and ensure you see the home screen is loaded in the Virtual device then start the application from Visual Studio. It will then install the apk into the Virtual device and launch your app.

See the sample image of SDK manager installation components

[image]

Comment: I update my post,in the sdk manager i installed every thing that is needed

Comment: it doesnt have everything, probably its not fetching everything from the server on the available list of components.

Comment: Do you know which components should i install?

Comment: i dont see system images in your snapshot. you need them for emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether  [**Visual Studio Emulator for Android**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) is installed or not.

If not installed, [click here](http://aka.ms/vscomemudownload) for download.

Documentation : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx

Steps to Install and configure **Visual Studio Emulator for Android** : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228279.aspx

---

---

```
Warning     @(Content) build action is not supported
```

There is a small workaround for this warning.

- Select `Properties` of `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Set `Build Action` as `None`

Comment: I Tried to install the Emulator for android but it says i cannot install it because i am using 32-bit windows, and now i am unable to find 32-bit version

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Xamarin Android Player: https://xamarin.com/android-player. I have found that it works very well and is pretty fast. I know the question was about VS's emulator, but this is a good alternative if you can't get that working.